# Does the sentence "no podemos esperar más" translate into English as "we cannot wait any longer" and "We cannot hope for more"?

Tags: traducción

Does the Spanish sentence:

> No podemos esperar más

have two translations into English ie.

1. we cannot wait any longer
2. we cannot hope for more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the verb "esperar" has the meanings of

1. Wait for, wait  <sub>(Esperar, aguardar)</sub>

> Estamos esperando a que pare de llover
>
> Espero a que llegue el autobús

2. Hope, trust  <sub>(Tener esperanza, confiar)</sub>

> Espero que deje de llover pronto
>
> Espero que el autobús llegue pronto
>
> No se puede esperar nada bueno de ti. Siempre me decepcionas.

Answer (score 2):

Both translations are reasonable. Without any context the first one (we cannot wait any longer) is the best one, but the second one is possible too. For the second meaning 'No podemos esperar *nada* más' would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

1. we cannot wait any longer

> No podemos esperar más.
>
> Espera a que llegue mi amigo.

It refers to time.

2. we cannot hope for more ?

> No podemos esperar más.
>
> Espero que llegue mi amigo. (Because something could have happened to
> him, so you wish/hope him to arrive).

It refers to have hope for something, or for someone.